# Android Firebase and Appmetrica conflict

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Firebase Realtime Database and Yandex Analytics (AppMetrica). When I am trying to use both this SDK's I got an error in Firebase Database:

```
    05-14 16:01:47.797 8194-8229/com.backgrounds.test:Metrica E/SQLiteLog: (5) database is locked
05-14 16:01:47.810 8194-8229/com.backgrounds.test:Metrica E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.backgrounds.test/databases/backgrounds-74bc1.firebaseio.com_default'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:635)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:321)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:295)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:216)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:194)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:200)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:192)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:864)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:849)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:724)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:295)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzu.zza(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzu.<init>(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzq.zza(Unknown Source:99)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzbz.zzq(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzck.zzca(Unknown Source:48)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzck.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzcl.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My app actually will not crash because this error is inside the process in which AppMetrica is running, but I continuously see the window "App has stopped".

Without AppMetrica being initialized everything works perfect and I got no errors at all. I know only that AppMetrica uses a separate process to run.
Can anyone explain me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Official doc](https://tech.yandex.com/appmetrica/doc/mobile-sdk-dg/concepts/android-initialize-docpage/):

> How the AppMetrica library works
>   The AppMetrica library consists of two sections: the client and the service.
>   The client section pre-validates data and transmits it to the service section, which is responsible for storing data and sending it to the server.
>   The service runs in a separate process. The reason for this is so the library has a minimal affect on the application in performance and memory. In addition, it frees the library from dependency on the stability of the app, so it can store and deliver data even if the app crashes or is unstable. However, this introduces certain specifics to working with AppMetrica.
>   If the app itself has multiple processes, the AppMetrica initialization must be performed the same way and using the same configuration. Otherwise, you could encounter a situation when the configuration of the AppMetrica library depends on which of the processes is initialized first (because each process has its own instance of the AppMetrica client part, while there is one shared service part).
>   We recommend initializing the AppMetrica library in the Application.onCreate() method (this way the library fulfills the Application.onCreate() method call in each process). However, you should account for the lifecycle of ContentProvider. There is no guarantee that an Application instance will be created before a ContentProvider instance is created. Also keep in mind that the code in the Application.onCreate() method runs for the service process as well.
>   So if you don't want some code executed more than once, don't put it in the Application.onCreate() method. It would be better to run this code when creating other components, or to put it in a separate Service. You should also avoid executing lengthy operations inside the Application.onCreate() method.

It's seems you should avoid access firebase from AppMetrica process. If it is not helped you provide more information about firebase usage.

Answer (score 0):

according to [appmetrica Installation and initialization](https://appmetrica.yandex.com/docs/mobile-sdk-dg/concepts/android-initialize.html), appmetrica  SDK creates a process with the name  PACKAGENAME:Metrica

for applications with more than one process, The code in the Application.onCreate() method runs for all processes. If you encounter an initialization error after integrating a third-party library (such as Firebase Cloud Messaging, realm, appcenter ...), make sure that the third-party library is initialized only in the main process. so you can do this:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (!isMainProcess()) {
           return;
        }
    // Initializing third-party libraries after verification.
    }
}
```

and the isMainProcess is:

```
  private boolean isMainProcess() {
        return getPackageName().equals(getMyProcessName());
  }
```